# Adding a blank line above and below the Argument Error message

Tags: ruby, exception

This is currently how I raise an Argument Error.

```
raise ArgumentError, "\n\n Critical Error: The input file doesn't exist\n\n"
```

When the error is raised, it produces a single line above and below the message; which makes it easier to see the message...

Since I raise a lot of errors in my script, I was wondering whether if I could somehow rewrite the ArgumentError method, so that I don't have to type the `\n\n` before and after each message.

I have looked around the net on how to do this but had no success.

EDIT:

As requested, here is a method in which I am raising Errors. I have loads of more of methods that also raise errors

```
 def input_file_format(input_file)
  unless File.exist?(input_file)
    raise ArgumentError,
          "\n\nCritical Error: The input file '#{input_file}' does not" \
          " exist.\n\n"
  end
  if File.zero?(input_file)
    raise ArgumentError,
          "\n\nCritical Error: The input file '#{input_file}' is empty.\n\n"
  end
end
```

Comment: why not a simple helper that can wrap the error messages with new lines?

Comment: @emaillenin agree with you also..

Comment: @emaillenin that is what I am looking to do, but I am not sure how to...

Comment: By default, you should not be able to raise more than one error per run. Since you are raising a lot of errors, you must have code that rescues the errors and somehow manipulate them. Show that part of code. Without that, you have not fully specified your condition, and your question remains unclear.

Comment: @sawa Good point,, I didn't think about that also,...

Comment: @sawa I meant I have many methods that raise errors when something goes wrong. I have edited the question to show the validator method that looks at the input file. So it would either raise the 'does not exist' error or the 'empty' error

Comment: Saw your edit. So you mean you are not raising more than one error per run, but you raise error from different places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution here is to create a simple method which throws the `ArgumentError` for you, and adds the newlines:

```
def error(msg)
  raise ArgumentError, "\n\n%s\n\n" % msg
end
```

Then you can just call this `error` method with an error message when you need it. You can extend this to support an additional argument to specify the error you want to raise if you throw various kinds of errors.

Comment: Why not just interpolate the string? `"\n\n#{msg}\n\n"`

Comment: Just for variation, not much of a difference? I like the String format syntax.

Comment: Put it where you want, as long as you can access it from where you want to call it. It's just a simple method. If you put it above your `ìnput_file_format` method, for example, it will work fine.